# Selenium framework data/keyword/hybrid/ Testng / webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, frameworks, testng

With reference to frameworks in selenium data/keyword/hybrid are called frameworks (Which is understandable) but even Testng and webdriver are also called frameworks. which leads to confusion, Please resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Framework is used because it provides you a great shortcut when developing applications since it contains lots of already written and tested functionality.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework)

> A software framework, in computer programming, is an abstraction in which common code providing generic functionality can be selectively overridden or specialized by user code providing specific functionality. Frameworks are a special case of software libraries in that they are reusable abstractions of code wrapped in a well-defined Application programming interface (API), yet they contain some key distinguishing features that separate them from normal libraries.

So `TestNg` is a unit testing framework which helps you to unit test your functionality by using `TestNg` already written libraries.

Same goes with `Selenium WebDriver`.

Whereas by using `Selenium WebDriver` library you can develop your own `DataDriven`, `Keyword Driven` or `Hybrid Framework` depending upon your application which you are going to test.

Hope this clarify your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following definition from Wikipedia's [Software framework](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) page should help:

> In computer programming, a software framework is an abstraction in which software providing generic functionality can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing application-specific software. A software framework is a universal, reusable software environment that provides particular functionality as part of a larger software platform to facilitate development of software applications, products and solutions. Software frameworks may include support programs, compilers, code libraries, tool sets, and application programming interfaces (APIs) that bring together all the different components to enable development of a project or solution.

According to the above definition, Selenium is a software framework as is TestNG. New frameworks can be created on top of existing frameworks such as Guru99's frameworks in [Creating Keyword & Hybrid Frameworks with Selenium](http://www.guru99.com/creating-keyword-hybrid-frameworks-with-selenium.html).

When you create a group of code to reuse that has default control flow but can also be extended to deviate from that default flow you've just created a framework (although perhaps an unnamed one).

Please see the entire Wikipedia article for more details (e.g. difference between frameworks and libraries, etc.).